# Iterate over ArrayList with JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have this Spring application. How to iteraete over allBooks in jsp file because in the way that i am trying it did not work. I do not know how to tell  the jsp file to get the list (allBooks).

Controller

```
@Controller
public class ListBooksController {

  @Autowired
  ListOfBooks listOfBooks;

  @RequestMapping("/books")
  public String books(Model model) {
    listOfBooks.addBooks();
    model.addAttribute("books", listOfBooks.listBooks());
    return "books";
  }

}
```

ListOfBooksImpl

```
@Repository
public class ListOfBooksImpl implements ListOfBooks {

  protected List<Book> allBooks = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public void addBooks() {
    Book tutun = new Book("Тютюн", "Димитър Талев", 50);
    Book lotr = new Book("Lord Of The Rings", "Tolkin", 35);
    allBooks.add(tutun);
    allBooks.add(lotr);
  }

  @Override
  public List<Book> listBooks() {
    return allBooks;
  }
}
```

Book

```
public class Book {

  private String bookName;
  private String author;
  private int price;

  public Book(String bookName, String author, int price) {
    this.bookName = bookName;
    this.author = author;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getBookName() {
    return bookName;
  }

  public void setBookName(String bookName) {
    this.bookName = bookName;
  }

  public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
  }

  public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
  }

  public int getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
  }
}
```

books.jsp

```
<body>
<section>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Books</h1>
            <p>All the available books in our store</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <c:forEach items="${allBooks}" var="book">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 15px">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>${book.name}</h3>
                        <p>${book.author}</p>
                        <p>$${book.price}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because you pass object named "books" not "allBooks"

```
model.addAttribute("books", listOfBooks.listBooks());
```

change to

```
model.addAttribute("allBooks", listOfBooks.listBooks());
```

and it will work

**EDIT**

so add the books to your collection first, probably it's empty

you have to call `listOfBooks.addBooks()` somewhere in your code (e.g create another controller method if you are just practicing it)

anyway you cant store the books like this in the array on the server because when you turn off your server all data will be gone, you have to persist data to the db

**EDIT 2**

According to your comments i can see that you dont understand how does model work, let me explain it for you:

when you wrote

```
model.addAttribute("books", listOfBooks.listBooks());
```

you added an array of books(List) to your model and assigned it as "books"

model is just a map containing key and value so you just simply added a key "books" with a value of List

nextly

you wrote in your view

```
  <c:forEach items="${allBooks}" var="book">
```

allBooks obviously doesn't exist in the model map, it doesn't matter what is the variable name in the object ListOfBooksImpl when you manually assigned the key to the List, you have a books key instead

**EDIT 3**

So if you want to add the books just create another controller method and invoke it first

```
@Controller
public class ListBooksController {

  @Autowired
  ListOfBooks listOfBooks;

  @RequestMapping("/addBooks")
  public String addBooks() {
    listOfBooks.addBooks();
    return "books";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/books")
  public String books(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("books", listOfBooks.listBooks());
    return "books";
  }

}
```

or if you want to add books only once

```
@Controller
public class ListBooksController {

  @Autowired
  ListOfBooks listOfBooks;

  @RequestMapping("/books")
  public String books(Model model) {
    if(listOfBooks.listBooks().isEmpty())
         listOfBooks.addBooks();
    model.addAttribute("books", listOfBooks.listBooks());
    return "books";
  }

}
```

Comment: After i added addBooks() to the interface it is working but everytime when i refresh the page it automatically add the same two entries to the list. I suppose that this is not the right place for calling this method.

Comment: @NoSuchUserException ofcourse it is not, you should first add these books to your db and then extract the data from db using your repository

Comment: @NoSuchUserException: This answer is based on assumption. If you really want a solution please reveal the exact problem that you are facing.

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung this is the problem... addBooks() method is called every time when i refresh the page because it is invoked in books() method which is in the controller. Now i am trying do call that method only.

Comment: @Oskar Dajnowicz now i am using only data structures. For now i will keep the project more simple.

Comment: so we fixed your problem, didnt we?

Comment: @Oskar Dajnowicz i am sorry but in my last post about your solution was not correct (i copy the wrong nick). I do not want to store an information. This project is for study purpose. I think that i have to make some service which will fill in the list and will be call only once but i do not now how to make it.

Comment: @NoSuchUserException now i hope my answer fits your needs

Comment: @Oskar Dajnowicz i saw your last edit. I understand what you are explaing to me but this is not the problem. I am trying to call the addBooks() method only once and i think that it must be called not in the contoller because if it is there the method is called every time when i refresh the page and it makes the same record every time.

Comment: @Oskar Dajnowicz now it works as i want. I understand that it will be more correct if i use a data base but for now i am just playing with Spring. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try it please.

```
<c:forEach items="${books}" var="book">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 15px">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>${book.bookName}</h3>
                    <p>${book.author}</p>
                    <p>${book.price}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: This is not the sollution. You use different variable and in that case it does not work at all.